# django Piston: How can I define custom methods in a handler?

Tags: django, django-piston

I have created a handler.py and want to write a method : getBooksForUser(). This method will return me all the books issued by a user. 
The documentation says :

> In addition to these, you may define any other methods you want. You
>   can use these by including their names in the fields directive, and by
>   doing so, the function will be called with a single argument: The
>   instance of the model. It can then return anything, and the return
>   value will be used as the value for that key.

in the fields, I have written the attributes of books that I want to return. Am i supposed to include the method name (getBooksForUser) here only?

please give me an example of code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the question about custom methods, but maybe helps solving your problem.

urls:

```
(r'^books\.json$', Resource(BookHandler)),
(r'^books/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)\.json$', Resource(BookHandler)),
```

handler:

```
   from piston.handler import BaseHandler
   from myapp.models import Book

   class BookHandler(BaseHandler):
      allowed_methods = ('GET',)
      model = Book   

      def read(self, request, user_id=None):
          base = Book.objects
          if user_id:
              return base.filter(user_id=user_id)
          return base.all()
```

I got the example from the documentation [here](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!resources):

Comment: I like this. This approach is much better as it is explicit and clear than the django-piston's recommendation of adding custom methods through fields ?? Feels very kludgy.